# Is it possible to create attack vectors based on referers?

Tags: security, http-referer

I had an idea while I was working on some PHP code. Usually, if a user is searching for a website on google and clicks on a link, the referer (in this case google, including search strings, etc.) the visiting website is getting this information.

do you think it is possible to create an attack vector out of the referal information? like: what could you do, if you know that the referer is maybe a site like paypal.com?

I'm looking forward to read your ideas about it!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, this is generally possible. The URL could contain sensitive information that is only meant for the visiting user of the origin web site.

An often mentioned example is the session ID that is used to identify the user’s session. If that session ID is leaked to a third party, the third party can try to use that session (known as [Session Hijacking](https://www.owasp.org/index.php/Session_hijacking_attack)). That’s why many web sites use a so called defererrer to strip out any possibly sensitive information when linking to third party sites.

Comment: yes indeed. I recently read something about phishing attacks through this because many people do not mind their URL bar and as long as a forwarded website, maybe called paypal-service.com, looks like the original one, useres might hand out sensitive information. but only because the attackers knows the user is a paypal user because of the referer.

Answer (score 1):

This [writeup](http://mixedbit.org/referer.html) explains how the `Referer` header can be exploited for a generic phishing attack.

Answer (score 0):

If the visitor is landing on your site after having visited a sensitive web server on another domain (i.e. paypal.com) chances are that this sensitive web server implements SSL.
If this is the case, most browsers will drop the referrer.